# Separar o zero das datas

Tags: php, data

Pessoal estou com uma dificuldade, como eu faço para tirar o zero quando eu puxo o date para uma variável ?

Exemplo:

```
$mesAtual = date("m");
var_dump($mesAtual);

resultado: 06 

ESPERADO: 6
```

Comment: converte para inteiro

Comment: Use *int* para forçar o valor para inteiro: `$mesAtual = (int) date("m")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça a conversão do retorno para o tipo inteiro:

```
$mesAtual = (int) date("m");
```

Desta forma, `var_dump` resultará em:

```
int(6)
```

Se preferir, pode utilizar a função [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.intval.php)

```
$mesAtual = intval(date("m"));
```

Esta função possui um segundo parâmetro que define a base numérica do resultado. Por padrão é 10 e por isso, neste caso, não precisa ser especificado. Um teste básico, utilizando diferenças de *microtimes*, indica que fazer apenas o *type cast* é mais rápido que fazer a chamada para a função (no Ideone se mostrou **muito** mais rápido).

```
define("START", microtime(TRUE));

$mesAtual = intval(date("m"));

define("MIDDLE", microtime(TRUE));

$mesAtual = (int) date("m");

define("END", microtime(TRUE));

echo "intval: ", MIDDLE - START, PHP_EOL;
echo "type cast: ", END - MIDDLE, PHP_EOL;
```

Resultado:

```
intval: 0.043507099151611
type cast: 3.814697265625E-6
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/IyPirp).

Comment: Muito Obrigada.

Comment: @CarolineSilveira, se a resposta resolveu o problema, pode marcar como resolvida.

Answer (score 4):

Basta que utilize o `n` ao invés de `m`, [segundo a documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php):

> Representação numérica de um mês, **sem zero à esquerda**

Portanto:

```
$mesAtual = date('n');
var_dump($mesAtual);

// = string(1) "6"
```

[Teste isto.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0c9a914bfe302e606375e9c8703f268c84835ea0)

Será suficiente, assim a representação será de 1 até 12, *ao invés de 01 até 12*.

Comment: Eu sabia que existia essa opção, olhei na documentação e não vi :(

Answer (score 0):

Usando Expressão regular  [exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/qx4GaT)

```
$stt = strftime('%m', strtotime("06/04/2017")); 

echo preg_replace('/0(\d)/', '$1', $stt);
```